# Texture won't apply to my model - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: texturing

So - I've created a 3D hexagonal prism, and I want to apply a sand texture I found online. When I add the nodes in the shading tool, I only get a color change, but no texture. I've tested the file on a plane and on the base cube, and both work fine, so I'm figuring it must have something to do with how I created the model:

I started by drawing a circle with 6 vertices and then selected all 6 vertices and pressed 'f' in order to fill out the 2D object. I then extruded the 6 vertices up in the Z direction in order to create a 3D object from the 2D hexagon.

When I apply the normal and height through a bump, nothing happens, and when I apply the color, it only changes the "base" color and not the texture. My nodes setup works fine on the base cube, as seen below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure to UV Unwrap the mesh? Planes and default cubes usually have the mesh unwrapped by default, however your custom model would not.

Comment: Ahh - thanks - that solved the problem. I mistakenly thought it would be applied instantly. This is my first attempt at a model, so still pretty new at this.